# Actualizar PartialView desde Formulario Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asincronismo

Tengo un formulario ajax.beginform con el que hago un registro y que al presionar el botón registrar debe actualizar un partialview que contiene una tabla en la misma página, pero siempre me muestra una nueva

```
<div class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Registrar", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "div_tabla_sucursal"
            }))
            {
            <div id="div_formulario_registrar_sucursal">
                @Html.Partial("_FormularioRegistrarSucursal")
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <div id="div_tabla_sucursal">
                @Html.Partial("_SucursalLista", lista_sucursal_index)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Sucursal/Sucursal.js"></script>
```

en mi controller tengo

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registrar(SucursalCLS oSucursalCLS)
{
//este accion le he cambiado el tipo de ActionResult, List<SucursalCLS>, JsonResult viceversa,con y sin [HttpPost] sin éxito
//List<SucursalCLS> a = new List<SucursalCLS>();
//que devuelva:
//return PartialView("_SucursalLista",ViewBag.lista_sucursal_index = a);
//return ViewBag.lista_sucursal_index = a;
//return a;
//return Josn(a JSonRequestBehavior,AllowGet),
//código
}
```

He probado distintos accion en mi controller y todos devuelven una página nueva

Así se debería mostrar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y todos devuelven esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo la librería Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax instalada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

habilitado en web.config
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes la librería `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` instalada?

Comment: Si, instalada, agregué una imagen para mostrar la librería instalada

Comment: En el Web.Config tienes habilitada esta línea? <add `key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`

Comment: Correcto, está habilitada, acabo de revisar, lo anexaré a mi pregunta con una imagen

Comment: No hace falta.. Pero los JS de Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax los tienes referenciados en la página?. No lo veo en el código de la Vista.

Comment: Acabo de corregir de
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
 a 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Sucursal/Sucursal.js"></script> y agregué las librerías a cada vista parcial... sin cambios

Answer (score 0):

En principio la configuración de Ajax la tienes correcta, así que el fallo lo estás teniendo en el Controlador.

En el Controlador debes devolver una Vista parcial, que se "incrustará" en el `<div />` `id="div_tabla_sucursal"` (`UpdateTargetId = "div_tabla_sucursal"`).

El código del Controlador sería algo así:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Registrar(SucursalCLS oSucursalCLS)
    {
        // Tu código aquí ...
        return PartialView("_SucursalList", TuModeloDeDatos);
    }
```

---

**Nota:** Para más información, y otras alternativas para trabajar con `@Ajax.BeginForm()` (Ajax Helpers) en ASP.NET MVC te recomiendo este artículo: [Formularios web AJAX en ASP.NET MVC 5 - Ajax Helpers](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/4/19/formularios-web-ajax-en-aspnet-mvc-5-ajax-helpers)

Comment: Cuando se llama la vista por primeravez, ese lista se carga desde ActionResult Index mediante un viewBag.MiModeloDeDatos, en el formullario llamo al actionResult Registrar y le doy "return PartialView("_SucursalList", ViewBag.MiModeloDeDatos);" eso me envía a otra vista, si lo hago "return PartialView("_SucursalList", TuModeloDeDatos);" como me indica en su respuesta en la vista parcial me indica "referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto" ya que el ViewBag que recibe no le llegó nada, revisaré el enlace que me envió, gracias.

Comment: Créate un Modelo de datos para la Vista parcial, e iguálalo a lo que tienes en el ViewBag. No debes pasar un ViewBag en el 2º parámetro de `return PartialView("_SucursalList", Modelo);`, pasa un Modelo y en la Vista parcial lo recibes mediante la directiva `@model`.

Comment: Tengo el index, en el tengo "@model List<SucursalCLS>" en la vista parcial tengo "@model" SucursalCLS porque ese es el modelo de mi formulario, y la vista parcial es "@model List<SucursalCLS>", si le quito el list en el model del index genera un error en la vista parcial de la lista y si se queda lo produce en la vista parcial del formulario.

Comment: Estaba revisando el enlace que me envió en su respuesta, vi que tiene una clase que denomina auxiliar llamada PostViewModel que me parece contiene la clase Post, me parece que sirve para solucionar lo mismo que escribí en mi comentario anterior o me equivoco?

Comment: Efectivamente, un `ViewModel` es una clase auxiliar que creamos para enviar datos a una `View` o una `PartialView` en tu caso. Crea un `ViewModel` con los datos que necesites (por ejemplo `List<SucursalCLS>`) y envíalos a la Vista parcial.

Comment: El contenido es buenisimo, lo malo es que no sé como adaptarlo a lo que tengo, soy nuevo en el entorno y no me es fácil implementar la metodología
using (bd){
var Lista_sucursal_a = bd.SP_SUCURSAL_LISTA().ToList();
foreach (var item in Lista_sucursal_a){
var asignar = new SucursalCLS
{iidsucursal = item.IIDSUCURSAL,
nombre = item.NOMBRE,
direccion = item.DIRECCION,
telefono = item.TELEFONO,
email = item.EMAIL,
MostraFechaCLS = item.FECHAAPERTURA};
ListaSucursales.Add(asignar);}
}return ListaSucursales;
así es como lo tengo, de implementar pero no tengo idea.